# SQL login exception from Visual Studio .NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I installed a Windows service on the local system while trying to connect to the DB. It’s giving an SQL login exception.

The service installed on the local system:

[image]

When debugging the code connecting to DB, it’s giving exception **"NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"**

[image]

ConnectionString= "Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=SQL2016;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Comment: It looks like your Windows service is running using an account that has no access to the database. You need to change the service to run using an account (new or existing) that does have access.

Comment: Does your service has a app.config? If so, do you have a connection string there? If so, could you share it?

Comment: ConnectionString= "Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=SQL2016;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Comment: What version (and edition) of Visual Studio?

Comment: `Data Source=SQL2016` means you're trying to connect to a remote computer. Unless both the client and server are in the same Active Directory Domain (which is common in companies), connections are made anonymously. If the machines are in the same domain, connections are made using the current user's account

Comment: As for `Windows service on the local system` using what account? The various service accounts (System, Local Service, Network Service etc) are all local.

Comment: Are you using `Local Service`? According to the [Service Account docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account), the System and Network Service accounts act as the computer on the network but Local Service `presents anonymous credentials on the network`

Comment: @Panagiotis Its Local System account

Comment: First, that's an awful idea - `System` can do anything on a machine. Never mind hacks, a simple bug, eg using a relative path, can delete system files. System's root folder is the `System32` folder. Second, you can't use it to connect to remote servers. To other servers it appears as the computer's account. Use a domain account instead

Comment: But have added domain credential under Windows credential manager it is connecting to SQL server when directly try to connect SQL2016 server no authentication issue.

Comment: But when try to connect from installed windows service its failing to connect throwing error “Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.)”

Comment: Could always allow mixed mode authentication on your SQL server, then use a known set of credentials in the connection string for this service